# Back pain after standing still but not after walking

Tags: running, walking, back-pain, lower-back

I was in public transport this day standing for about an hour. Now I noticed that I got quite a noticeable pain in my lower back (only 19 yo). I have noticed in the past that my lower back would hurt quite fast when standing still.

When I'm running or walking, I do not have this issue, able to walk 4 hours straight without a lower back pain.

So my question is, do more people have this issue and can it be explained?

*(If not then this would be a general health issue and I would need to go to the doctor or a physician.)*

> always seek a Physician's opinion before acting on any advise that has potential to worsen a condition.

From: 
[How to prevent back pain after a long day of standing](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/6101/how-to-prevent-back-pain-after-a-long-day-of-standing) (not just about standing still)

I'm not seeking advice, I'm seeking an explanation for why standing still for a longer time would hurt my back but walking for a couple hours wouldn't.

Comment: Bad posture combined with standing on a vibrating platform can compound your back. Combine that with a relatively weak back form desk work and you have a recipe for pain.

Comment: And would it be possible to get better over time? f.e. standing 2/3x a week so you kind of train your back to become stronger and take the hits?

Comment: Your body becomes good at what it does most. If you want to train your back, do deadlifts.

Answer (score 1):

More people do have this issue and similar issues. Generally, being still for long periods isn't easy on the body. Even if you have good posture, standing still for long periods of time can be hard to tolerate, especially if you have greatly increased how much time you stand for. People who sit for long periods of time have issues. Even people on bed rest who don't move get issues. We are built to move. Pain may still indicate a good reason to go to the doctor.

Something else you could start with right away:
1. Take movement breaks every 20 minutes - walk, as you say that feels better. If you are stuck on public transit try walking on the spot. Others might think you need to pee, but it is worth it :)
2. Do a quick posture check in every 20 minutes [here is a video example](https://youtu.be/sQWG-krTyZY) of checking in and reseting your posture.